# Haskell: foldr vs foldr1

Tags: haskell, fold

If I have this insert function:

```
insert x []     = [x]
insert x (h:t)
  | x <= h      = x:(h:t)
  | otherwise   = h:(insert x t)
```

this produces a sorted list:

```
foldr insert [] [1,19,-2,7,43]
```

but this:

```
foldr1 insert [1,19,-2,7,43]
```

produces '*cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]*'

I'm confused about why the second call cannot work.

I have looked at the definitions for both [foldr](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr_f.html) and [foldr1](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr1_f.html) and have traced both with simple arithmetic functions, but I still cannot come up with a clear explanation for why the second call fails.

Answer (score 16):

Let's look at some type signatures.

```
foldr  :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) ->      [a] -> a
```

In both cases, the first argument is a function of two arguments.

- for `foldr1`, these two arguments must have the same type (and the result has this type also)
- for `foldr`, these two arguments may have different types (and the result has the same type as the second argument)

What's the type of your `insert`?

Answer (score 11):

I like the type-based answers given here, but I also want to give an operational one explaining why we don't want this to typecheck. Let's take the source of `foldr1` to start with:

```
foldr1          :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
foldr1 _ [x]    = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
```

Now, let's try running your program.

```
foldr1 insert [1,19,-2,7,43]
= { list syntax }
foldr1 insert (1:[19,-2,7,43])
= { definition of foldr1 }
insert 1 (foldr1 insert [19,-2,7,43])
= { three copies of the above two steps }
insert 1 (insert 19 (insert (-2) (insert 7 (foldr1 insert [43]))))
= { definition of foldr1 }
insert 1 (insert 19 (insert (-2) (insert 7 43)))
```

...whoops! That `insert 7 43` is never going to work. =)

Answer (score 4):

The type of `foldr1` is `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`, i.e. arguments and result of this function have the same type. However, `insert` has type `Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]`. For `foldr1 insert` being well-typed, `a` and `[a]` must be the same type.

But this would mean that `a == [a] == [[a]] == [[[a]]] == ...`, i.e., `a` being a type of infinitely many lists.

Answer (score 1):

Because `foldr1` is trying to do this:

```
insert 43 -7
```

which will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is following:

`foldr` would do this way:

1. result set to `insert 43 []`
2. result set to `insert 7 result`
3. and so on

This clearly works.

Whereas `foldr1` would try to do the following:

1. result set to `insert 7 43`
2. result set to `insert -2 result`
3. etc.

which is definitely wrong. You can see, `foldr1` requires the arguments to the operation to be of the same type, which is not the case for `insert`.